# Linux mysql server 5.6 will not start, or restart

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with mysql server; it doesn't want to start
do you have an idea

thank you.

```
    janv. 29 10:51:15 clicshopping mysqld_safe[20076]: 160129 10:51:15 mysqld_safe Can't log to error log and syslog at the same time.  Remove all --log-error configuration options for --syslog to take effect.
janv. 29 10:51:15 clicshopping mysqld_safe[20076]: 160129 10:51:15 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
janv. 29 10:51:15 clicshopping mysqld_safe[20076]: 160129 10:51:15 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
janv. 29 10:51:15 clicshopping mysqld_safe[20076]: 160129 10:51:15 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
janv. 29 10:51:55 clicshopping sudo[19837]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

My process

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo service apparmor stop
sudo mv /var/lib/mysql /home/mysql
sudo ln -s /home/mysql /var/lib/mysql
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /home/mysql
vi /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld (change var/lib/mysql ot /home/mysql)
sudo service apparmor start
sudo service mysql start
```

after deleted /var/log/mysql/error.log : results

```
mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
2016-01-29 11:21:17 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2016-01-29 11:21:17 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.10.1) starting as process 27093 ...
2016-01-29 11:21:17 27093 [Warning] Buffered warning: Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)

2016-01-29 11:21:17 27093 [Warning] Buffered warning: Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)

2016-01-29 11:21:17 27093 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2016-01-29 11:21:17 27093 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
2016-01-29 11:21:17 27093 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2016-01-29 11:21:17 27093 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-01-29 11:21:17 27093 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-01-29 11:21:17 27093 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2016-01-29 11:21:17 27093 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-01-29 11:21:17 27093 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2016-01-29 11:21:17 27093 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2016-01-29 11:21:17 27093 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-01-29 11:21:17 27093 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2016-01-29 11:21:17 27093 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
```

Comment: The solution is in the error above - `Remove all --log-error configuration options for --syslog to take effect.`

Comment: in var/log/mysql/error.log, i deleted all data, does'nt work :see above

Comment: How about posting your my.cnf, since that's what MySQL uses for configuration?

Comment: It's not asking you to delete the log file. It's asking you to change the configuration to never try to write to that file in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

`Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql`

You didn't change the datadir in /etc/my.cnf or wherever your distro places it. Changing it to `datadir=/home/mysql` should fix your problem.

Comment: I have this element.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. I did notice another error - `2016-01-29 11:21:17 27093 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.`. Are you sure you're not missing any tables?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your 'mysql.plugin' table is not exsist or mysql data dir is not owned by mysql user.

Answer (score 0):

The very first line tells you about the problem:

> janv. 29 10:51:15 clicshopping mysqld_safe[20076]: 160129 10:51:15 mysqld_safe Can't log to error log and syslog at the same time.  Remove all --log-error configuration options for --syslog to take effect.

You responded to that by saying this:

> in var/log/mysql/error.log, i deleted all data, does'nt work :see above

But you *missed the point*!  MySql doesn't care what data is or is not in that file. It cares that you're still trying to write new data to the file. You need to *change your configuration file* so you never try to write to that log in the first place. Alternatively, you could remove the `--syslog` option. You get to write to one or the other log location; not both.

Also, what in the world did you do to your plugin table!?

> 2016-01-29 11:21:17 27093 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.

As it suggests, try running `mysql_upgrade`.

Comment: I reinstall all and it work ! tk